# draw line using div html

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have use the following code snippet.

to display the data:

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <div style=" height: 100px;overflow: scroll;">
        <table >
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>2</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="line" style="left:10px; width: 1px;  position: absolute;height: 30px; background: red;top: 0px;" >
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here I have give the `30px` height is by hard code to draw the line. I want to draw the line for full table but in run time I can not get the table height. how to draw the line for full table.

I have tried with auto instead of `30px` but it did not working for me. How  to resolve this problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/48yxg/ is this you want ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer in my working scenorio i want to place the another layer above the table using div for display some thing(expample line). how to achieve this while with out know the height of the table. It is possible to achieve this

Comment: you can get the height of table using jquery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/48yxg/4/ check this

Answer (score 2):

Its nothing just try to use table border.. for example visit http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: From OP's comment: "`i want to place the another layer above the table...`" The line is just an example...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to draw table border, use the following CSS:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LT8U2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a solution using your method!

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <div style=" height: 100px;overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="line" style="left 10px; width: 1px; float:left; position: relative;height: 30%; background: red;top: 0px;" ></div>
            <table style="float:left; position:relative; left: 10px;" >
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>2</td></tr>  
                 ....
```

Just use float left and a percent size to position and size the div correctly based on the container size!
heres a demo because everyone else did one http://jsfiddle.net/VLbVw/

Comment: your solution is drawn the border only based on the height of 100px in the above code . i want to show the border the border while scrolling the div also. Can you please check your solution in this border did not drawn fully even it will be set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

you can put first row of the table as line and put your stuff befor table. give width of table as 100%

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
        <div style=" height: 100px;overflow: scroll; border-left:1px solid red;">
        <!-- put your stuff here-->
        <div>Hi there !!!</div>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tbody>
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <!-- this div represent the line-->
                         <div class="line" style="height:1px;background: green;top: 0px;" >                                    
                      </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                    <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                    <tr><td>1</td></tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes does the trick:

CSS:

```
.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div style="position: relative">
        <table >
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>      
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>  
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice, that when you use `position: absolute`, you need to position also the parent element. Relatively positioned `div` is the "layer" here, and it will be automatically fitted to the height of its content.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TgD6/).